# Carto.js + Highcharts.js - Time series

Tags: carto, sql, api, chart

I am trying to plot dates and values from carto.js ( using the sql API) into highchart.js . [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/pabloska/de731b8797c72384fb4fe9ac348f73f1) uses the following data structure [Date.UTC(2013,5,5),0.7638] ,but  how can I covert the the data returned after the sql request into this data structure [Date.UTC(2013,5,5),0.7638] ?? Any idea??

Answer (score 1):

I'm following the code that you have [here](http://bl.ocks.org/pabloska/de731b8797c72384fb4fe9ac348f73f1).
You would need to set a new variable that will store the pairs of values of `date` and `deaths_mis` from your CARTO dataset.

In order to do so, I would recommend create a global variable before setting the sql in the code. The new variable stores an empty array that will store the pairs is `dataStructure`.

```
    var dataStructure = []
    var sql = cartodb.SQL({ user: 'migrantreport' });
    sql.execute("SELECT date,SUM (deaths_mis) deaths_mis FROM iom_world_deaths_copy GROUP BY date order BY date asc")
```

Then, when you do the for (i in data.rows) to retrieve teh data of CARTO, I would recommend pushing the values inside the dataStructure array.

```
for (i in data.rows){
                dataStructure.push([data.rows[i].date,data.rows[i].deaths_mis])
            }
```

Finally, you can use the `dataStructure` pairs of values within the Highcart.js parameter `data`

```
  series: [{
            type: 'area',
            name: 'Migrant Deaths',

           data: dataStructure
        }]
```